# Normalizing constant in posterior distribution formula when (improper) prior is uniform over real line?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

Suppose there is a parameter $\theta$, that we do not know. What we do know is some random variable 
$$
Y=\theta + \epsilon
$$
where $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ is independent of $\theta$. Then $f_{Y\vert\theta}(y\vert \theta) \sim N(\theta,1)$, where $f$ denotes a PDF.

Since we do not know $\theta$, **suppose that  that $\theta$ is drawn from an (improper) uniform prior over the real line** (but we still don't know what it is)

The definition of the posterior distribution is 
$$\tag{1}
f_{\theta\vert Y}(x\vert y)=\frac{f_{\theta}(x)\cdot f_{Y\vert\theta}(y\vert x)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{\theta}(x)\cdot f_{Y\vert\theta}(y\vert x)dx}
$$
because $f_\theta(x) =1,\  \forall x$ (since improper prior uniform over reals) we have that the integrand is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{Y\vert\theta}(y\vert x)dx = \infty
$$
Therefore the posterior is improper? Have I made a mistake?

To me the above seems incorrect, because I believe that $E[\theta\vert Y=y] =y$, and seeing as the mean is a property of a distribution, doesn't this mean that the conditional distribution exists?

I realize that if I have the prior be uniform over a large interval like $(-1000000,1000000)$, then the denominator is not $\infty$, but then the prior is also not improper...

**To clarify the question:** If we have an prior that is uniform over the reals, and $Y$ as above, does the conditional distribution $(1)$ exist, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unconditional distribution of $Y$--that is to say, your denominator--is $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty f_\theta(x) f_{Y \mid \theta}(y \mid x) \, dx = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty 1 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(y - x)^2/2} \, dx = 1.$$  Thus, it too is improper, but the posterior distribution of $\theta$ is not:  it is $$f_{\theta \mid Y}(x \mid y) = f_{Y \mid \theta}(y \mid x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(y-x)^2/2},$$ hence is normal with mean $y$ and variance $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I messed up the integration somehow, so I checked it with a computer, but apparently I made a mistake inputting the code, too... I just tried again and you are right, the denominator (the unconditional distribution) is $1$, not $\infty$. Thank you.