# Calculating posterior with Improper uniform prior

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, bayesian

There is a random variable $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and assume an improper uniform prior for $\theta.$ Let $\epsilon \sim N(0,1),$ independent of $\theta.$ Then you're given the noisy signal $s = \theta + \epsilon.$
We want to find $Pr(\theta < \theta^* \mid s)$ where $\theta^*$ is some known threshold value.

My old notes calculates this to be $Pr(\epsilon > s - \theta^*) = 1 - \Phi(s-\theta^*),$ but I think we should be getting $Pr(\theta < \theta^* \mid s) = Pr(\epsilon > s - \theta^* \mid s)$ instead, conditioning on $s,$ but I'm not sure how this is evaluated using the improper prior of $\theta.$

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. By definition, the posterior distribution is $$f_{\Theta \mid S} (\theta \mid s) = \frac{ f_{\Theta} (\theta)  f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta)      }{  \int_{\mathbb{R}}  f_{\Theta} (\theta) f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta)   d \theta     }$$

The conditional distribution density $f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta) = \phi(s - \theta)$ since $S = \Theta + \epsilon$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0,1).$ Using the uniform prior $f_{\Theta} (\theta) = 1,$ we have
$$f_{\Theta \mid S} (\theta \mid s) = \frac{f_{\Theta} (\theta) f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta) }{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{\Theta} (\theta) f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta) d \theta} = \frac{1 \cdot f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta) }{\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1 \cdot f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta) d \theta} = \frac{f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta) }{1} = f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta) = \phi(s - \theta),$$
so $\Theta \mid S \sim N(s, 1).$

So thus $Pr(\Theta < \theta^* \mid s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\theta^*} f_{\Theta \mid S} (\theta \mid s) d \theta= \int_{-\infty}^{\theta^*} \phi(s - \theta) d \theta = 1 - \Phi(s - \theta^*).$

It should be noted that the result is dependent on the prior being improper uniform on $\mathbb{R},$ as in general $f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y) \neq f_{Y \mid X} (y \mid x).$

For example, if instead $\Theta \in [a,b]$ and our prior is $U[a,b],$ we would get the posterior equals (after cancelling $f_{\Theta} (\theta) = \frac{1}{b-a}$ from numerator and denominator)
$$f_{\Theta \mid S} (\theta \mid s) = \frac{ f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta) }{ \int_{a}^{b} f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta) d \theta} = \frac{\phi(s-\theta)}{\int_{a}^{b} \phi(s-\theta) d\theta} = \frac{\phi(s-\theta)}{\Phi(s-a) - \Phi(s-b)} \neq \phi(s-\theta) = f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta)$$ Though as we let this approach the improper uniform prior, $a \to -\infty, b \to \infty,$ this does approach $\phi(s-\theta) / (1-0) = \phi(s-\theta)$ as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think your notation is causing your confusion, so I will rewrite some of it.

$\Theta$ is your improper prior and $\epsilon$ is your standard normal noise.  Then $S = \Theta + \epsilon$ is the signal.  You want to compute $$\Pr[\Theta < \theta^* \mid S = s].$$  In other words, given that you **observed** the signal $S = s$, you want the probability that $\Theta$ is less than some known $\theta^*$.  Then this is $$\Pr[\Theta < \theta^* \mid S = s] = \Pr[S - \epsilon < \theta^* \mid S = s] = \Pr[s - \epsilon < \theta^*] = \Pr[\epsilon > s - \theta^*].$$
The first equality is simply the application of $S = \Theta + \epsilon$ by definition.  The second follows by applying the conditional statement $S = s$ to the criterion $S - \epsilon < \theta^*$.  After we apply it, because $\epsilon$ is independent noise and $\theta^*$ is a constant, it is no longer required to write the conditional $S = s$.  The third equality is simply algebraic rearrangement, now noting that $s$ and $\theta^*$ are fixed constants and $\epsilon$ is the only random variable in the probability statement.

Comment: Yes, I do know that what I'm looking at is $Pr[\Theta < \theta^* \mid S = s]$ is $Pr[S - \epsilon < \theta^* \mid S = s]$ but I'm not sure why you can drop the condition here?
because we're looking at something of the form $Pr[X < x \mid Z = z]$ where $Z = X + Y$ and isn't this equal to $Pr[Y > z - x \mid Z = z] \neq Pr[Y = z - x]$?

Comment: @Roy Let me give you an example.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables.  Then $$\Pr[X + Y \le 5 \mid X = 3] = \Pr[3 + Y \le 5].$$  Do you still need to write $\Pr[3 + Y \le 5 \mid X = 3]$?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I do see that $Pr[X+Y = z \mid X = x] = Pr[Y = z - x]$
But on the other hand, $Pr[X = x \mid X+Y = z]$ I don't think is equal to $Pr[Y = z-x]$? \\

For example, if I roll a fair six sided die $X$ and I roll a fair ten sided die $Y$ then consider $Pr[X = 1 \mid X+Y = 2] = 1$ this isn't the same as $Pr[Y = 1] = 1/10$?

Comment: I think I'm not sure about the step $Pr[Z - Y < x \mid Z = z]$ and why this is equal to $Pr[z - Y < x]$? Writing it out I get $Pr[Z - Y < x \mid Z = z] = \frac{Pr[Z - Y < x, Z = z]}{Pr[Z = z]} = \frac{Pr[Z = z, Y > z - x]}{Pr[Z = z]}$ but $Z=z, Y > z - x$ aren't independent?

Comment: Maybe a point of clarification - is $S$ still a random variable in this case?

Comment: I don't think $\epsilon$ and $S$ are independent though?

Comment: Ok I finally figured it out. I don't think you can simply "apply" the condition $S = s$ in general. It only works here because of the improper prior in particular. Following the calculations in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220041/normalizing-constant-in-posterior-distribution-formula-when-improper-prior-is
We can see that the densities $f_{\Theta \mid S} (\theta \mid s) = f_{S \mid \Theta} (s \mid \theta)$ only because the denominator is $1.$ For example, if instead our prior for $\Theta \in [a,b]$ was $U[a,b]$ then the posterior is $ \frac{\phi(s-\theta)}{\Phi(s-a) - \Phi(s-b)}$